# Twisted klein with Marshmallow

Tags: python, twisted

I am getting started with twisted klein, and was already able to insert data in the database with txmongo.

I did it creating a database model:

```
class Database():

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.mongo_uri = uri
        self.mongo = None
        self.db = None

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def initialize(self):
        if self.db is None:
            self.mongo =  yield ConnectionPool(self.mongo_uri)
            self.db = self.mongo.local

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def insert(self, collection, data):
        yield self.db[collection].insert(data)
```

and then invoking the insert method in the controller:

```
@app.route('/teste', methods=['POST'])
def save_item(request):
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    body = json.loads(request.content.read())
    db.insert('teste', body)
    return json.dumps({'success': True})
```

It worked, but I have two questions:

1. Is this working asyncronously?
2. Can I use the Marshmallow library to
   serialize and validate data with twisted klein?

Comment: (1) yes (2) why not

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just get too edgy working with twisted, wondering if I will block the whole thing. I did the insert method without the decorator and it worked too, so its still a little confusing for me. Do you know any way I can automatically test if the implementation is trully async?

Comment: Oof.  That's a deep question and the answer won't fit in a comment.  A superficial answer could be that if it returns a Deferred it is async.  If it doesn't return a Deferred (but returns some other result) it is not async.  That hides a lot of subtleties though so don't quote me on it.  But in your code, it appears as though the two `insert` methods return a Deferred so it seems like you're okay.  (Though you drop the `db.insert` Deferred on the floor so you're not going to notice errors, though you will still report success.)

Comment: Could you check my last answer to see if its a better implementation?

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed the later implementation. Now my dao.py file looks like this:

```
from txmongo.connection import ConnectionPool
from twisted.internet import defer

class Database():

    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.mongo_uri = uri
        self.mongo = None
        self.db = None

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def initialize(self):
        if self.db is None:
            self.mongo =  yield ConnectionPool(self.mongo_uri)
            self.db = self.mongo.local

    def insert(self, collection, data):
        return self.db[collection].insert(data)

    def drop(self, collection):
        return self.db[collection].drop()
```

My controllers.py file looks like this:

```
from application import app, db
from twisted.internet import defer
from bson.json_util import dumps

@app.route('/')
def home(request):
    return 'Hello, world!'

@app.route('/teste', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE'])
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def teste(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = json.loads(request.content.read())
        yield db.insert('teste', body)
        defer.returnValue(return_json(request, {'success': True}))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        body = yield db.find_one('teste', {})
        defer.returnValue(return_json(request, body))
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        yield db.drop('teste')
        defer.returnValue(return_json(request, {'success': True}))

def return_json(request, result):
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return dumps(result)
```

Now I can make a simple CRUD (missing the update though) asyncronously.

Comment: You might want to handle exceptions from `yield db...` to return a nicer failure response.  I forget what Klein will do with an unhandled exception from a route handler but it's probably not what you want ideally.